Extracting "words" from string
I have some strings in the following format:
"John Smith The Last"
"Jane Smith The Best"

From each of these strings, I want to extract the "names" (that is, "John Smith" and "Jane Smith") as well as the "honorifics" (that is, "The Last", "The Best"), but could not find a way of achieving this.
I have tried to use the str_extract_all() and str_split() functions from the stringr package, as follows:
library(stringr)
name <- str_extract_all(my_str, boundary("word"))

This just returns a list of one element ("Jane Smith The Best").
I have also tried:
name <- str_split(my_str, " ", n=3)

This also seems to return a list of one element ("Jane" "Smith" "The Best").
I am looking for a base R or stringr solution.

Is the pattern always like that? I.e. is it possible to split on the second white space? Then we might adapt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295325/how-to-separate-values-in-a-string-only-after-the-second-space

you could also split with a lookahead, e.g. str_split(my_str, " (?=The)"). It depends on the overall pattern though. Need more examples

I should just plus your comment, but split on the look ahead...OK.

Edit: adding ignore.case = TRUE and space in gsub pattern
One way to extract the "names" and the "honorifics" is by using gsub() and using the first word that identifies the honorific names, such as the, The, der, or any other identifier as the pattern in gsub(). Here is an example, which I edited based on good suggestions from @Mark and @L Tyrone:
strings <- c(
  "John Smith The Last",
  "Jane Smith The Best",
  "Alfonso the Warrior",
  "Ferdinand the Artist-King",
  "Ludwig der Bayer",
  "Theodore Thea the Great", 
  "John the Theologian"
)




honors <- gsub(".*(the |der )", "\\1", strings, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
names <- gsub("(?= the | der ).*", "\\1", ignore.case = TRUE, strings, perl = TRUE)
data.frame(names, honors)
# names          honors
# 1    John Smith        The Last
# 2    Jane Smith        The Best
# 3       Alfonso     the Warrior
# 4     Ferdinand the Artist-King
# 5        Ludwig       der Bayer
# 6 Theodore Thea       the Great
# 7          John  the Theologian


.*(the|der) pattern looks for texts that begin with the or The or der.
ignore.case = TRUE ignore the variations in lowercase and uppercase in the pattern, so the, The, THE, etc are all detected as valid patterns.
"\\1" means to substitute the texts that match the above pattern with itself. This means to print the texts.
?= the means to look for texts that are followed by  the.

This answer is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012902/14812170 and the suggestions in the comments.

you can use the parameter ignore.case = TRUE instead of listing out variations on the capitalisation

it's standard in R to use <- when assigning variables, not =

I would also say, there's plenty of surnames which include  der , see https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=der+surname&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1

Also won't work for people named Theodore or Thea etc.

Thanks @Mark and @L Tyrone. I have edited my answer based on your suggestions.

@AbdurRohman the names one looks better, but the honors one is still odd. Are you familiar with lookbehinds? Also, I think this would be a lot simpler just using str_split, as in the original post. Don't repeat yourself

I'm not very familiar with lookbehinds, or regex in general. I try .*(?<=(the|der)) for honors and it works, but I feel .*(the|der)" is easier to read.  Also, I like gsub because it returns  a character vector, not list, and  because OP is looking for base R options too.

another example: John the Theologian

@Mark: Nice catch. Thanks. Need to add space in gsub for honors. Please see my edited answer.
